# save ELKI output to a file

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan, elki

I want to save the cluster outputs to a file. for example I want to save cluster1 points into c1.txt and cluster2 points into c2.txt and so on.
ELKI release 0.7

```
java -jar elki.jar -dbc.in ./f1 -dbc.out ./dir1 -algorithm clustering.DBSCAN -dbscan.epsilon 5 -dbscan.minpts 10
```

but it has this error:

```
the following parameter were not processed: [-dbc.out,./dir1]
```

The command could not be correct, so how can I save clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save to a file, use

```
-resulthandler ResultWriter
-out folder/
```

to limit what files are being written, you can use `-out.filter`.